# npm pip.py ENOENT error while creating a React Native Project

Tags: python, node.js, react-native, npm, pip

In order to create a React Native Project I followed these steps:

1. installing node.js
2. and executing this command: `npx create-expo-app AwesomeProject`

The first problem I have is that I have this error: `'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognize as an internal command`

The second is this:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip.py
npm ERR! path C:\Users\nicol
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip.py ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I don't have python 3.9 installed on my computer and this path (C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip.py) does not even exists.

To fix the problem, I checked all my env variables and none of them refers to the previous path. My pip is located here: C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts

I decided to uninstall node js and pyhton and reinstall them but nothing changed.

I tried to force npm to use the correct python path with this command `npm config set python "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe"` but it does not work as the new versions of npm do not accept 'python' as a valid option.

I have the npm 9.8.1 version.

I am kind of lost thank you very much for your help !